# Adding unique indexes which start with "A" go up to 99 (A1-A99) and then start again "B1" and continue up to B99 and so on?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, cursor, python-parser

i want to add unique indexes which have to start with "A" go up to 99 (A1-A99) once the 99 rows of finished it has start again "B1" and to continue up to B99, so this index system  has to continue with alphabetic order (A,B,C) with number system (1-99).

How do I do it in the field calculator of ArcGIS Desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use Python and the [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead of Field Calculator. It will give you much more flexibility. You can execute the code in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm) of ArcMap. If it runs out of letters and digits it will not restart, only leave empty rows.

```
import arcpy, string

feature_class = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class' #Change to match your data
unique_field = r'unique' #Change to match the name of your id field

id_generator = (letter+str(digit) for letter in string.ascii_uppercase for digit in range(1,100))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, unique_field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(id_generator)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Screenshot from ArcGIS Pro but it is the same in ArcGIS-desktop:

[image]

Comment: i need another clarification, if letters runs out due to large number of data, is it possible to return something like ("AA1", "AA2...., BB1)?

Comment: Yes, but it would be easier to increase the range, for example A1 to A1000. Just change `range(1,100)` to `range(1,1000)`.

Comment: Or if you are ok with AA1, AA2 .. AZ99: `id_generator = (letter+letter2+str(digit) for letter in string.ascii_uppercase for letter2 in string.ascii_uppercase for digit in range(1,100))`

Comment: thanks for that, because i wanted to limit the numbers within two digits

Comment: if you don't mind could you please describe, how to incorporate the above code into the model builder as the python script tool

Comment: @S.JP Try it yourself: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm . If you get stuck post a new question